# Break a string into multiple lines

Tags: php

I need to split a sentence/string into small chunks based on a particular string length. PHP's str_split function is doing half of the work; I need to retain a full word. In other words, I do not want a word to be separated abruptly into two at the end of each line. I cannot figure out the solution. It will be of great help if you suggest me something.

Here is the code and the result so far.

```
$line = "After six months, participants in both vitamin D supplementation groups had lost more weight and had greater reductions in their waistlines than those who hadn't taken the supplements, Vigna's team said";
$chunks = str_split($line, 35);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($chunks, true);




Array
(
    [0] => After six months, participants in b
    [1] => oth vitamin D supplementation group
    [2] => s had lost more weight and had grea
    [3] => ter reductions in their waistlines 
    [4] => than those who hadn't taken the sup
    [5] => plements, Vigna's team said
)
```

Comment: is 35 the max length on each line?

Comment: See if wordwrap gives you teh nice result: http://php.net/wordwrap

Comment: what you could do is explode the string then pending on how many words you want in a line piece it together. http://php.net/explode

Comment: Yes, your suggestion just solved my problem. I used explode and wordwrap together.